# How to get varargs as a string?

Tags: vimscript

Say I have a function that takes multiple arguments, how would I pass them as a single string argument to another function?

```
function test(...)
    " vimgrep is just an example
    vimgrep a:000 /some/path/**/*.txt
endfunction
```

When bound to a key, eg

```
command! -nargs=+ FIND call SimpleGrep(<args>)
nnoremap <M-f> :FIND<SPACE>
```

I get the error that the input is an unknown variable, using `string(a:000)` doesn't fix things.

How would `a:000` be converted into a string so `FIND a b c` could be evaluated as if `FIND "a b c"` had been written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the arguments together with `join()`.

```
function test(...)
    " vimgrep is just an example
    execute 'vimgrep /'.join(a:000).'/ /some/path/**/*.txt'
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ FIND call SimpleGrep(<f-args>)
nnoremap <M-f> :FIND<SPACE>
```

Note: `join()` will join together with a single space and `<f-args>` will ignore extra spaces, so `:FIND a b c` is equivalent to `:FIND a     b    c`

For more help see:

```
:h join()
:h <f-args>
:h a:000
```

Comment: Not sure escaping is correct here, needed to do `execute 'vimgrep '.join(a:000) l:root`  (l:root is the variable for the root dir).

Comment: In this case, the space stripping is a bit of a problem, possibly better to manually quote the string then. Even so, handy to know how to join varargs.